# IBM Bluemix SQL Database service data store management

Tags: db2, ibm-bluemix

I'm working on IBM Bluemix SQL Database service with premium plan. According to our application the sql service can have many schemas.

Is there any way to seperate data storage of each schema to different physical storage and manage them as individual(file, file group etc.)

For example: The tables and data on SchemaUser1 stored in SQLDBFile1 and SchemaUser2's tables and data stored in SQLDBFile2 Is it possible to create schemas like this? or the only way to separate datastore is creating a new sql database service.

Comment: There is no relationship between physical storage and the logical schema. Example S1.T1 IN TS1, S1.T2 IN TS2, S2.T1 IN TS2 and S2.T2 IN TS1 is possible. You need to manually make sure that all tables in schema s1 ends up in TS1, etc. If you have different user/group/roles for different schemas you can use GRANT at tablespace level to make sure that only a particular schema user can create tables in a certain tablespace, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003304.html .

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, schemas have no clue about their physical background such as tablespaces; they mean only logical namespaces.
But it does not mean you cannot do the schema->tablespace relation yourselves by using the IN tspacename clause in create commands provided that the referred tablespaces already exist.